# .htaccess subfolder not working getting error

Tags: .htaccess, localhost, http-status-code-404

I m getting .htaccess subfolder error
I have a subfolder localhost/folder/subfolder/
my  site under folder is running excellent but when i try to open subfolder 404 page opens

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{index} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: Why do you claim that the error has anything to do with the `.htaccess` style file?

Comment: `%{index}` is not a variable.